# Возможно ли сократить?

Tags: c#

```
if (Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].LastConnectIp == null) {
    if (player.Ip == Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].RegisterIp) {
        Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].Auth = Users.PlayerFlags.Idle;
        Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].LastConnectIp = Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].ConnectIp;
        Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].ConnectIp = player.Ip;
        JsonHelper.SaveFile(Api.PlayerCache, "Users.json");
    } else {
        Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].Auth = Users.PlayerFlags.Auth;
    }
} else {
    if (Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].LastConnectIp == player.Ip) {
        Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].Auth = Users.PlayerFlags.Idle;
        Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].LastConnectIp = Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].ConnectIp;
        Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].ConnectIp = player.Ip;
        JsonHelper.SaveFile(Api.PlayerCache, "Users.json");
    } else {
        Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].Auth = Users.PlayerFlags.Auth;
    }
}
```

Возможно хоть чуть-чуть сократить?
Может дополнение какое-нибудь есть для VS2017? Resharper не предлагать так как он установлен

Answer (score 4):

Если присмотреться, то разница заключается только в том, с чем сравнивается `player.Ip`. Остальные строки идентичные.

Правило сравнения можно описать так:

Если есть `LastConnectIp`, то сравнивать с ним, если нет с `RegisterIp`.

Для этого отлично подойдет [оператор `??`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator):

```
if ((Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].LastConnectIp ?? Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].RegisterIp) == player.Ip) {
    Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].Auth = Users.PlayerFlags.Idle;
    Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].LastConnectIp = Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].ConnectIp;
    Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].ConnectIp = player.Ip;
    JsonHelper.SaveFile(Api.PlayerCache, "Users.json");
} else {
    Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid].Auth = Users.PlayerFlags.Auth;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, но жалуется что не может bool и string привести к ??

Comment: @Сергей, скобочками оберни. Поправил в ответе

Answer (score 4):

Ну например так:

```
var currPlayer = Api.PlayerCache[player.Uid];
var ip = currPlayer.LastConnectIp ?? currPlayer.RegisterIp;
if (ip == player.Ip) {
    currPlayer.Auth = Users.PlayerFlags.Idle;
    currPlayer.LastConnectIp = currPlayer.ConnectIp;
    currPlayer.ConnectIp = player.Ip;
    JsonHelper.SaveFile(Api.PlayerCache, "Users.json");
} else {
    currPlayer.Auth = Users.PlayerFlags.Auth;
}
```